# Increment counter inside an array

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to increment (using a counter) the value of a C# array. However I always get an

```
Index out of bounds error.
```

Here is my code. I am trying to increment the next position of the counter inside datesStrings array but the error stops it. How should I increment the value of "i"?

```
string[] datesStrings = { "" };      
int i = 0;

    if (counterDays.DayOfWeek.ToString() == "Monday")
            {
                datesStrings[i] = counterDays.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                i++;
            }
            else 
            {
                counterDays = counterDays.AddDays(1);
                i++;
            }
```

Any suggestions? TIA.

Comment: Why don't you just use a `List<string>`? Lists make your life so much easier than arrays...

Comment: Your array only has one element, at `i = 0`. So what else did you expect than that the code would fail if you set `i = 1`? Question is, what _is_ is that you want?

Comment: Just edited my code. The point of my code was to find out if the current day placed on counterDays is Monday or not. If yes, the current value wil be placed on datesStrings variable. Otherwise, the code will continue adding days to counterDays variable.

Comment: The main idea is that an array is not dynamic. You can't change it's capacity specified when you created it. This `string[] datesStrings = { "" };` declares an array which can hold only one element. Increasing your `i` counter has no effect on the array capacity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because your array is 1 element long, change to `List<string>();`

```
List<string> datesStrings = new List<string>();     

if (counterDays.DayOfWeek.ToString() == "Monday")
{
    datesStrings.Add(counterDays.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));         
}
```

EDIT:

create method:

```
public IEnumerable<DateTime> EachDay(DateTime from, DateTime thru)
{
    for(var day = from.Date; day.Date <= thru.Date; day = day.AddDays(1))
        yield return day;
}
```

and use it

```
var mondaysStrings = EachDay(counterDays, DateTime)
                   .Where(x=>x.DayOfWeek==DayOfWeek.Monday)
                   .Select(x=>x.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

it will select all mondays from day range from `counterDays` till `DateTime.Now`, you can change your date range to whatever you want

Comment: my counter days is declared like this:

DateTime previousMonth = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);
DateTime counterDays = previousMonth;

Comment: @vishnu check my edited answer, it contains cleaner approach for your task

Comment: The goal of my code was to get the weeks 1 month prior to the current date but I will checkout your code and see how it works. Thanks

Comment: @vishnu it does exactly what you just said. It takes all mondays from last month

Comment: yeah, will check but I was trying to really get the entire week (days) of each week 1 month prior to my current date. Thanks

Comment: thanks. It does get all mondays. Will play with it in order to get the range of each week now. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You have only 1 (0) position:

```
string[] datesStrings = { "" };
```

How do you want to go ahead to 1, 2, 3...?

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the length of string array before using it, 
like this

```
string[] datesString = new string[10]; // whatever the size of array you want to create.
```

Then implement your logic in the code. it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't sure you need that exactly, but that's the most elegant approach

```
//Create string list
List<string> datesStrings = new List<string>();
//Find all date items with Monday     
IEnumerable<DateTime> foundValues = counterDays.Where(result => result.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday);
//Add found dates string representation to list
foreach(DateTime value in foundValues)
{
    datesStrings.Add(value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
}
```